# How to show an image instead of providing an link to it?

Tags: html, css

I can't show an image instead it's a link. I try everything i could.

I try the image path and it's right. Then, the tag, which also is right, I believe. Then, the format, it looks correct and acts good.
Here's the code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e9ff99;
  background-image: radial-gradient(at 9% 89%, hsla(215, 90%, 73%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(at 72% 6%, hsla(331, 74%, 64%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(at 24% 19%, hsla(14, 90%, 74%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(at 65% 6%, hsla(6, 79%, 76%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(at 20% 98%, hsla(316, 72%, 64%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(at 44% 9%, hsla(40, 96%, 77%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(at 10% 9%, hsla(76, 65%, 63%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%);
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.glass-container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 72vw;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(11.6px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(11.6px);
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

ul.nav-links {
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li.nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 10vh;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.main h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
}

.main p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 23px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

button:hover {
  border-color: #2668db;
  background-color: #2668db;
}

.image-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.attrebute {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1075px) {
  .content {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .logo {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  li.nav-link {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  .main h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  .main p {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  button {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  .image-wrapper img {
    max-width: 400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="glass-container">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="logo"><a href="#">Anna Lin</a></div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="main">
          <h2>Hey!<br>It's Anna</h2>
          <p>
            I'm Anna Lin, a dedicated Full Stack Developer and Software Engineer. My passion lies in crafting efficient and robust applications that seamlessly blend innovation and functionality.</p>
          <button>Get Started</button>
        </div>
        <div class="image-wrapper">
          <img src="image.png">
          <div class="attrebute">
            <a href="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/98/0a/e5/980ae5677bdda92012bf2d588948ba6f.jpg">Image</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Image i wanted to show: [The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWHnU.jpg)

The code snippet above contains the html and css for the page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't want to show the link but the image?
so you don't have to use the **[a](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)** tag but the **[img](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)** tag

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

*{
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}

body{
color: #fff;
background-color: #e9ff99;
background-image:
    radial-gradient(at 9% 89%, hsla(215, 90%, 73%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%),
    radial-gradient(at 72% 6%, hsla(331, 74%, 64%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%),
    radial-gradient(at 24% 19%, hsla(14, 90%, 74%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%),
    radial-gradient(at 65% 6%, hsla(6, 79%, 76%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%),
    radial-gradient(at 20% 98%, hsla(316, 72%, 64%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%),
    radial-gradient(at 44% 9%, hsla(40, 96%, 77%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%),
    radial-gradient(at 10% 9%, hsla(76, 65%, 63%, 1) 0px, transparent 50%);
min-height: 100vh;
}

.container{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

.glass-container{
display: block;
max-width: 72vw;
margin-top: 10vh;
margin-bottom: 30px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
padding: 50px;
border-radius: 16px;
box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
backdrop-filter: blur(11.6px);
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(11.6px);
}

.logo{
display: inline-block;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 600;
margin-top: -10px;
}

ul.nav-links{
margin: 0;
float: right;
display: flex;
list-style: none;
}

li.nav-link{
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 30px;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: 300;
}

.content{
display: flex;
width: 100%;
}

.main{
margin-top: 10vh;
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px;
}

.main h2{
font-size: 35px;
}

.main p{
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 23px;
}

button{
margin-top: 10px;
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
font-size: 15px;
color: #fff;
background-color: transparent;
border: 1px solid #fff;
border-radius: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

button:hover{
border-color: #2668db;
background-color: #2668db;
}

.image-wrapper{
display: flex;
margin-top: 5vh;
position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper img{
max-width: 500px;
}

.attrebute{
position: absolute;
bottom: 20px;
right: 0;
font-size: 12px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1075px) {
.content{
    flex-direction: column;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
.logo{
    font-size: 22px;
}
li.nav-link{
    font-size: 13px;
}
.main h2{
    font-size: 28px;
}
.main p{
    font-size: 15px;
}
button{
    font-size: 13px;
}
.image-wrapper img{
    max-width: 400px;
}
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Anna's Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="glass-container">
        <nav class="navbar">
          <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">Anna Lin</a>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li class="nav-link">
              <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link">
              <a href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link">
              <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="main">
            <h2>Hey! <br>It's Anna </h2>
            <p> I'm Anna Lin, a dedicated Full Stack Developer and Software Engineer. My passion lies in crafting efficient and robust applications that seamlessly blend innovation and functionality.</p>
            <button>Get Started</button>
          </div>
          <div class="image-wrapper">
            <div class="attrebute">
              <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/98/0a/e5/980ae5677bdda92012bf2d588948ba6f.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the error is that you are placing [your image](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/98/0a/e5/980ae5677bdda92012bf2d588948ba6f.jpg) in the **[a](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)** tag instead of the **[img](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)** tag